# Optimizing Delivery Routes in a Graph-Based Network to Minimize Maximum Delivery Time

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, graph-traversal

In a graph with `N` nodes, where each node represents a house and is labeled from `0` to `N-1`, an adjacency matrix `graph[i][j]` indicates the distance from node `i` to node `j`.

Consider a list of tuples `[[init_1, target_1], ..., [init_k, target_k]]`, representing delivery requests. Each tuple, like `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 3]]`, requires a delivery person to transport food from `init_i` to `target_i` (e.g., from houses 1, 2, 5 to houses 2, 3). **Each delivery person can carry an unlimited amount of items/orders at same time.**

There is also a list of delivery personnel `[v1, v2, ..., vn]`, where each `vi` indicates the current location (node) of the `i`-th delivery person. Assuming all personnel move at the same speed and ignore the stopping time at each node, how can one assign a route to each (a list of houses for pickup and delivery) to minimize the maximum time taken by any delivery person?

Comment: Can the delivery persons carry more than one order at a time?

Comment: @Steven Yes. Each delivery person can carry an unlimited amount of items.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unlikely to admit any efficient solution since it is NP-Hard even when there is only one delivery person and, for all edges $(u,v)$ in the graph, the distance between $u$ and $v$ is $1$.

To see this let $G=(V, E)$ be the graph and let $V = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$.
Construct a new graph $H = (V', E')$ where $V' = V \cup \{ s, u_1, \dots, u_n\}$ (where $s$ and $u_1, \dots, u_n$ are new nodes) and $E' = E \cup  \{ (s,v_i) \mid i =1,\dots, n\} \cup \{ (u_i, v_i) \mid  i= 1,\dots, n \}$ (if you are interested in directed graphs then add also the revers edges $(v_i, u_i)$).

Let $s$ be the starting location of the only delivery person. There are $n$ deliveries, the $i$-th delivery requires food to be transported food $u_i$ to $v_i$.

There is a route on $H$ that delivers all the food and has length at most $3n$ if and only if $G$ is hamiltonian.